# How to get element position from p:Diagram Element when it is dragged

Tags: primefaces, element, draggable, diagram

I have a simple p:Diagram with some elements that are rendered in a specific order. 
Now the problem is that my backingbean needs to obtain and persist the position when the user moves the an element from the original position.

I've read the primefaces documentation and i could not find any event or way to obtain the client x/y coordinates when the element is being dragged.

Comment: Me neither! I have to find a way to store the coordinates for each element on the diagram.